# How to detect mouse position and click on a shape in userform of VBA

Tags: excel, timer, mouseevent, userform, vba

I'm working on a excel userform, and I'm really curious if there is any way to track the mouse position and mouse click(single click) on a userform in VBA?

For example, I want to measure the reaction time between two clicks and report their distance on a userform; to do so, I first add two circle shapes on userform randomly, and then I want to start timing after clicking on one circle, and end timing after clicking on the other.

To be more specific, is there any way to:
1. Detect a mouse click on a shape on userform
2. Detect the mouse position after a click on a userform

Is mouseevent still useful in this case? Thank you very much!

Comment: Were you able to use the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the shape as an image to your UserForm and use `Private Sub Image1_Click()`. You can track the time within the click events and use the position of the images to track the distance.